# Weird counting of "consecutive" visits. Bug?

Tags: bug

Right now, I see in my profile (from main, not meta):

```
visited 149 days, 4 consecutive
```

But yesterday, I saw... `17 consecutive` (not 100% sure about the 7, but certain about being in the teens). About 30min ago, I saw 3 days (assuming the day clock just passed in SF).

How can the counter possibly be incremented like this?

I don't post (ie be active) every day, but I do visit everyday. So, I don't understand why my consecutive days getting reset.

Comment: Timewarp perhaps? :)

Comment: Are you looking at your [SF profile](http://serverfault.com/users/96562/grumpy) or [meta.SF profile](http://meta.serverfault.com/users/96562/grumpy)?  Each may have different consecutive counts based on your activity.

Comment: Considering I rarely ever visit meta, I'm sure it's about my main SF profile.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers - thanks. Now I have that stupid song stuck in my head. "It's just a jump to the left..." GRAHAHHHHHHHHHHH FLASHBACKS TO HIGH SCHOOL... GREMLINS... No̺͈͋ơ͈̳̬̻̰̩̦͊̓̅o͉͔͙͑͑ͪ̒̌̈o̷͕̾͛̆ͤͯ̓͒o̸̹̲̾̇ǒ̴͂͌o̵̬͚̥͕̭̦ͯ͗̿ooooooo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Stack Exchange sites use UTC to delineate days.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27201/189912) If you don't visit between 00:00 UTC of one day and 00:00 UTC of the next, then you lose.

You also have to actually visit the site, such as viewing a question. [Just loading the home page doesn't count.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/189912)

A diamond moderator should be able to view your login activity and tell you with some certainty what happened....

Comment: @grumpy The system does indeed think you missed a day (4 days ago), and UTC days are probably the reason.  If you're badge-hunting I suggest visiting every day at the same time (and making sure that's a time reasonably close to Noon UTC if practical, so you have lots of wiggle room) and trying to find something vote-worthy (or browsing a few questions & making sure the system registers your visit on your profile before you leave).

Comment: Ah, the "just loading the home page doesn't count" kind of answers the question. I often browse front page and go if nothing that interests me. Though, I swear I saw a higher consecutive days just yesterday (well, 2 days now)... :( I'm gonna blame timewarp now.

Comment: I suggest you put together a list of your favorite tags, which you can then browse. You may find it easier to find interesting questions that way.

Comment: Plus having favorite tags highlights them on the front page(s) so you can spot questions you might be interested in.